# How do I delete a file who's path is in Real Time DB?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am running Firebase and inside the realtime database I save a filename of the current file I want to load. I then use Cloud function to create thumbnails. When I change the file I am trying to create a Cloud Function to delete the thumbnails? This is what I currently have and I am able to load the full path. `object` is not available for I can't load the bucket.

```
exports.deleteThumbnails = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/avatar').onUpdate(event => {
    const prevAvatar = event.data.previous.val();
    const filePath = `${event.params.userId}/avatar/40_${prevAvatar}`;
    console.log(`FilePath: ${filePath}`);

    // const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket);
    // const file = bucket.file(filePath);
    // const pr = file.delete();

    return event;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your full path is where you have stored the file in firebase storage then the following code should help:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET_NAME>.appspot.com"
});

var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
exports.deleteThumbnails = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/avatar').onUpdate(event => {
    const prevAvatar = event.data.previous.val();
    const filePath = `${event.params.userId}/avatar/40_${prevAvatar}`;
    console.log(`FilePath: ${filePath}`);
    return bucket.file(filePath)
        .delete()
        .then(() => {
             console.log(`file deleted.`);
        })
        .catch(err => {
             console.error('ERROR:', err);
        });
});
```

To understand all the operations on the file go through this : [Google cloud storage Uploading, Downloading, and Deleting Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics) and visit [Firebase storage for admin sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start) to understand how admin sdk works with storage follow this:

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Getting and error with this code.
`TypeError: admin.storage is not a function`

Comment: Can you send the package.json file? Because in my code I have just done  var admin = require("firebase-admin"); var bucket = admin.storage().bucket(); and the exports.deleteThumbnails...... It is working fine.

Comment: oh ok...most probably I am running and old package:

{
 "name": "functions",
 "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
 "dependencies": {
  "@google-cloud/storage": "^0.4.0",
  "firebase-admin": "^4.1.2",
  "firebase-functions": "^0.5",
  "lodash": "^4.17.4",
  "request-promise": "^2.0.0",
  "sharp": "^0.18.4"
 },
 "private": true
}

Comment: updated firebase-admin and everything worked flawlessly.